# Values of the components NOT to disappear after ajax submit in WICKET

Tags: ajax, onclick, submit, wicket

I have a `Panel` (WICKET), and in this panel, I have 2 `TextFields` and a SUBMIT `AjaxLink`. If I click on the SUBMIT button, I write this code in the submit ajax link's `onClick()` method:

```
target.add(form);
```

Than the form will be updated, and the values in the textfields will be disappear.
It is only an example, my code is not interesting. But what I want to know: is there any way, to NOT to disappear the values from the form's textfields after ajax submit?

Comment: Did you set a Model for the TextFields?

Comment: not yet. using  only String

Comment: Could you please post more code, even if it seems uninteresing?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what your code is but i assume you used this Constructor:

```
TextField(String id)
```

You should instead be using this Constructor (which also sets a Model, which contains the Text content of the TextField)

```
TextField(String id, IModel<T> model)
```

You can for example create a TextField like this:

```
TextField<String> textField = new TextField<String>("id", Model.of("Text content"));
```

See http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/TextField.html for more information about TextFields